# Why does dplyr::do() allow . to refer to the current group, but dplyr::summarise() does not?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am currently scratching my head about a specific behavior in `dplyr` that I cannot seem to understand. For grouped data, `do` allows `.` operations on the current group, but in `summarise` `.` refers to the whole data and not to each group. Why is this the case?

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame( 
  hour     = factor(rep(1:24, each = 21)),
  price    = runif(504, min = -10, max = 125)
)

df %>% group_by(hour) %>% 
  summarise(mean(price))
# # A tibble: 24 x 2
#     hour `mean(price)`
#   <fctr>         <dbl>
# 1      1      58.78788
# 2      2      55.51119
# 3      3      54.44470
# [...]


df %>% group_by(hour) %>% 
  summarise(mean(.$price))
# # A tibble: 24 x 2
#      hour `mean(.$price)`
#    <fctr>           <dbl>
#  1      1        54.66447
#  2      2        54.66447
#  3      3        54.66447
# [...]

mean(df$price)
# [1] 54.66447


df %>% group_by(hour) %>% 
  do(as.data.frame(mean(.$price)))
# # A tibble: 24 x 2
# # Groups:   hour [24]
#      hour `mean(.$price)`
#    <fctr>           <dbl>
#  1      1        58.78788
#  2      2        55.51119
#  3      3        54.44470
# [...]
```

As one can see, only `summarise` without `.` and `do` with `.` produce the expected results (i.e., aggregate over the grouping variable). `summarise` with `.` simply returns the overall `mean`.

I know that why questions are perhaps not the most suitable questions for SO, but as `dplyr` is supposed to be intuitive and this does not seem intuitive to me at all, I hope this is okay.

Comment: Because you are getting the `mean` of the entire column by extracting `.$price`.  It is like doing `mean(df$price)`.  The reason why `do` does that and `summarise` don't do should be related to the source code.  In `summarise`, the default option is to just specify the column name after grouping.  So, if you want to extract the column as `.$price`, it will do that for the entire column (and it may be useful in some situations).  In `do`, if we want to do that, you may refer as `mean(df$price)` instead

Comment: As `df$price` is possible in both `summarise` and `do` my question kind of remains. Is there a specific reason why the syntax differs here in this kind of subtle way?